# Where do I find short-term house share offers in Auckland?

Tags: accommodation, rental, new-zealand, auckland

I'd like to rent a room in Auckland for two months starting in mid-January.
I have generally liked having house mates, so I'd like to look for something like that.

What websites or other sources should I use to find accommodation like that?

In Germany, I know http://wg-gesucht.de and similar things; In the UK I found a room through http://easyroommate.co.uk, but the corresponding http://easyroommate.co.nz does not give me any results at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some resources I found via a couple [secondary](https://www.reddit.com/r/auckland/comments/365h24/hey_guys_what_is_nz_equivalent_to_gumtree_or_say/) [sources](https://www.tvnz.co.nz/one-news/business/gumtree-to-shut-down-new-zealand-operation-6245319) after a quick Google:

- **[holidayhouses.co.nz](http://www.holidayhouses.co.nz/)** is a holiday rental website run by TradeMe, NZ's eBay equivalent. Bring your own housemate--or maybe use nzflatmates to find one?
- **[nzflatmates](http://www.nzflatmates.co.nz/)** is a dedicated housemate-search website. You fill in a profile and match up with someone with spare room.
- **[Post a Note](https://postanote.co.nz/)**, NZ's craigslist, has a housing and property section. You'd probably be able to find room lets/flatshares as well as entire flats on here.

There's also the ubiquitous **[Airbnb](http://www.airbnb.co.nz/)**, which operates in NZ and provides more peace of mind than craigslist-style websites at the cost of higher fees. Like with Post a Note, here you can find either flatshares or entire homes.

Comment: nzflatmates does not seem to know the concept of “staying from”, not to mention “staying until” or any other non-geographical filters.